# Fragment with RecyclerView inserted into compose does not scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose, android-scrollview

I have a fragment that implements `RecyclerView` that I have included in jetpack compose view via `AndroidView`. I have pager, one page is in compose and second is in the old style.

Example of whole screen

```
Column(
   modifier = Modifier
       .fillMaxSize()
       .verticalScroll(scrollState)
) {
    HorizontalPager(
         modifier = Modifier
             .fillMaxHeight()
             .nestedScroll(rememberNestedScroll(scrollState = scrollState)),
         count = pages.size,
         state = pagerState,
     ) { page ->
          when (val detailPage = pages[page]) {
            is oldlayout -> convertToCompose(
                  modifier = Modifier
                      .fillMaxSize()
                      .scrollable(scrollState, Orientation.Vertical)
             )
             is compose -> ....

}


convertToCompose(modifier: Modifier) {
    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        AndroidView(
            modifier = modifier,
            factory = { context ->
               ......
            ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(this, true)

    }
}
```

It looks like compose and recyclerview scrolls are not compatible. Compose view scroll works with example of the above. When I'll remove `verticalScroll(scrollState)` compose scroll stops working and vica versa, the recyclerview starts working.

Is there any possible way how to forward NestedScroll from compose to old xml layout? I tried it according to [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/touch-input/gestures#parent-compose-child-view) and it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use  `coordinatorlayout` + `appbarlayout` + `RecycleView`

Then Use : RecycleView Item to fill the `compose view`